# Enable jumping to the list of questions from site account screens in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, android-app

Navigating to a site I'm a member of but not on my shortcut list (in the left slide-in panel) requires 3 taps and anything from 3 to 8 scrolls or typing 3 or more letters, all the while having to remember which sites I am logged into from a list of dozens of irrelevant ones. Overall, it's a tedious affair.

In the normal browser, it takes only 4 mouse clicks and maybe one scroll action (account link -> "View more" (full list of accounts) -> target site user page -> "Questions"), and I'm not presented with cognitive noise.

Would be nice if the official Stack Exchange app could allow one to jump to the site one is subscribed to through the user account screen, for instance, via tapping on the user's avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding something here, but it seems like you want to use the "Your Profile" section to help you navigate to the sites quickly rather than to view your profile on them.

It doesn't make much sense to me to put hidden triggers to view a site in a page that doesn't relate to the questions on that site at all. Your site profile is *your* activity on the site.

Are you talking about quickly getting to a generic site's questions page? If so, the best way to do that is really to hit "All Sites" in the left sidebar and just type in the few first characters of the site's name, the same as using the quick-switcher in the top bar on the desktop.

Are you instead talking about viewing *your own* questions on a site? That's something that's already on the profile page but I might be misunderstanding. Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: I agree that undiscoverable features aren't welcome. However, the list of all sites is way too broad; I read regularly only a subset (more than 6) which I'd like to have handy.

Comment: @DeerHunter can you not select them from the All Sites page and pin them to the left nav?

Comment: Aw shucks. You can close the request now!